# How to nest two seperate Json entities, one containing the other?

Tags: json, azure-mobile-services

I have a drawing app which saves drawing data to SQLite on a device. One of db the fields contain actual drawn items as these items are serialised to Json so that they can be deserialised and edited on the drawing.

When sync'ing with Azure App Services, a whole drawing record is serialised to Json which would then contain the already-serialised drawn objects in that one field..., then sent to the app service.

Should the CONTAINED Json, ie: the serialised drawn objects be wrapped in a way so as to allow THAT Json data to be inserted into ONE given field in the App Services db?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if you serialize a object to json string and store it into a field of your local SQLite table, after sync with your remote table, the json string would also within a field under your remote table.

The syncing operation for uploading your local item to the remote table would look like this:

[image]

Then, you could retrieve the previous inserted record from your remote table as follows:

[image]

In general, when working with Azure Mobile Apps, we would choose SQL Database as our storage. You could leverage SSMS or SQL Server Object Explorer or other client tools to connect to your SQL database.

Moreover, if you are implementing the relationship between entities, I would recommend you use the flat model. Details you could follow adrian hall's book about [Relationships](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/relationships/).

Comment: Bruce, that is exactly the answer and information I was looking for.

The db on the client/device side is SQLite and using SQLite-Net Extensions in Xamarin.Forms. This handles all relationships 1:N, N:N etc. I will look into SSMS and SSOE too as well as implementing a flat model...

The db in Azure App Services is SQL Server. The user never saves directly to the app service but the app syncs with said service at various intervals.

You've certainly given me excellent advice to build on. Thank you.

Comment: For offline sync, you could follow [Enable offline sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data) and adrian hall's book about [The Mobile Client](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/). Any concerns, feel free to let us know. If my answer could help you, kindly mark it as an acceptable answer.